# Array of types responding to protocol in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, types, static, swift3

I'm looking for a way to create an array of *types responding to a protocol* in **Swift 3**.

Here's my problem (simplified for the example), I have a protocol called `Rule`:

```
protocol Rule {
    static func check(_ system: MySystem) -> [Inconsistency]
}
```

and some types responding to the Rule protocol:

```
struct FirstRule : Rule {
    static func check(_ system: MySystem) -> [Inconsistency] {
        ...
    }
}

struct SecondRule : Rule {
    static func check(_ system: MySystem) -> [Inconsistency] {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I wish to check my system this way :

```
let system = MySystem()
let inconsistencies = system.check([FirstRule, SecondRule])
```

In order to do that I just have to write a simple extension:

```
extension MySystem {
    func check(_ rules : [????]) -> [Inconsistency] {
        var result = [Inconsistency]()

        for rule in rules {
            result += rule.check(self)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

So what would be the type of the `rules` array?

Of course I wish to keep the rule checking static, and do not want to create instances (in that case the type would be `[Rule]` and it would be much easier).

So if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you talking about an array of `Rule.Type`?

Comment: Thanks! I answered before I saw your comment!

Comment: Darned interesting. I was actually tempted to say it was impossible. Then I realized it wasn't. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to figure this out if you simplify away everything but the essentials:

```
protocol Rule {
    static func check()
}
struct S1 : Rule {
    static func check() {}
}
struct S2 : Rule {
    static func check() {}
}
```

And now:

```
let arr : [Rule.Type] = [S1.self, S2.self]
for thing in arr {
    thing.check()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Damn! I've just found it! It's `Rule.Type`:

But I have to add `.self` to the types:

```
let inconsistencies = system.check([FirstRule.self, SecondRule.self])
func check(_ rules : [Rule.Type]) -> [Inconsistency]
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think that's what I said.